# R:how to calculate poblational standard deviation and mean

Tags: r

I was looking for the steps to calculate the standard deviation of a population in R and I found this:

```
sqrt((n-1)/n) * sd(x) # pop
    ## [1] 0.8936971

    sd(x) # sample
    ## [1] 0.8981994
```

The problem is that I´m completely lost do not know how to extrapolate the formula to my data :

```
YEAR
2003
2004
2005
2006
2007
2008
2009
2010
2011
2012
2013



 GDP
7696034.9
8690254.3
9424601.9
10520792.8
11399472.2
12256863.6
12072541.6
13266857.9
14527336.9
15599270.7
16078959.8
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: why do you think you have a problem with your data?

Comment: I do not understand what do you mean by your question? you have already add the formula and you cannot then used it with your data!

Comment: I very much doubt that the concept of standard deviation applies to your case, it seems you need a linear model such as `fit <- lm(GDP ~ YEAR); plot(YEAR, GDP); abline(fit, col = "red")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
y <- c(2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007,2008,2009,2010, 2011,2012,2013)

> n <- length(y)
> sqrt((n-1)/n)*sd(y)
[1] 3.162278

> GDP <- c( 7696034.9, 8690254.3, 9424601.9, 10520792.8, 11399472.2,12256863.6,12072541.6,13266857.9,14527336.9,15599270.7,16078959.8)
> m <- length(GDP)
> sqrt((m-1)/m)*sd(GDP)
[1] 2633634
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the data in a dataframe `df`

Then use

```
sd(df$GDP)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
My_list <- list(YEAR, GDP)
my_sd <- sapply(My_list, function (x) sd(x))
my_sd
[1] 3.316625e+00 2.762179e+06
```

and also you can use this:

```
> My_sd_pop <- sapply(My_list, function (x) {sqrt((length(x)-1) /length(x)) * sd(x)})
> My_sd_pop
[1] 3.162278e+00 2.633634e+06
```